# Store strings into array of strings with scanf

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, scanf

Trying to store input into array of strings with following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int noOfStrings;
    printf("Enter no of strings: ");
    scanf("%d", &noOfStrings);
    char *string[noOfStrings];
    for(int i=0; i<noOfStrings; i++){
        printf("\nEnter string %d: ", i);
        scanf("%s\n",string[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console:
Enter no of strings: 3                                                                                                   

Enter string 0: abc                                                                                                      

Enter string 1: def                                                                                                      

Enter string 2: ghi                                                                                                      

Segmentation fault (core dumped)                                                                                         


...Program finished with exit code 139                                                                                   
Press ENTER to exit console.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not able to figure out why this is failing.

I also Tried following code with fixed size array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int noOfStrings;
    printf("Enter no of strings: ");
    scanf("%d", &noOfStrings);
    char string[noOfStrings][5];
    for(int i=0; i<noOfStrings; i++){
        printf("\nEnter string %d: ", i);
        scanf("%s\n",string[i]);
    }
    printf("\nPrinting Stored Strings");
    for(int i=0; i<noOfStrings; i++){
        printf("\nEnter string %d: ", i);
        printf("%s\n",string[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console:
Enter no of strings: 3                                                                                                 

Enter string 0: abc                                                                                                    
def                                                                                                                    

Enter string 1: ghi                                                                                                    

Enter string 2: jkl                                                                                                    

Printing Stored Strings                                                                                                
Enter string 0: abc

Enter string 1: def                                                                                                    

Enter string 2: ghi                                                                                                    


...Program finished with exit code 0                                                                                   
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

After entering 1st string ('abc') There was no prompt for 2nd string, so proceeded by entering 'def'. Followed by 2 more strings. Notice that string 'jkl'  is not printed.

Please tell me what i am missing in these 2 cases?

Thanks.

Comment: And in first case you declare array of pointers and each pointers needs to be allocated memory before dereferencing .

Comment: @xing I tried removing the \n in both cases I got the following outputs:

Case 1-
Enter no of strings: 3

Enter string 0: abc
def

Enter string 1: ghi

Enter string 2: jkl

Printing Stored Strings
Enter string 0: abc
Enter string 1: def
Enter string 2: ghi

Case 2-
Enter no of strings: 3

Enter string 0: abc
def

Enter string 1: ghi

Enter string 2: jkl

Printing Stored Strings
Enter string 0: abc
Enter string 1: def
Enter string 2: ghi

Comment: Every time you read user input with `*scanf()` and don't check the return value, that's relying on the user to *not* invoke undefined behaviour of your program. Don't do that.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Understood :)

Comment: @DevSolar I did not understand your comment. Do you mean that i should check that the return value of scanf is 1?

Comment: Exactly. You might be using `noOfStrings` uninitialized, if what the user entered didn't match what your `scanf()` expected.

Comment: @DevSolar Understood :)

Comment: @xing Error from my side suggested change fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you're defining an array of pointers:

```
char *string[noOfStrings];
```

However, these pointers are uninitialized.  When you then attempt to use `scanf`, you dereference these invalid pointers.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case causes a crash.

Your second case fixes this by using a 2D array of characters big enough to hold the strings you input.  But you get stuck because of your `scanf` format:

```
scanf("%s\n",string[i]);
```

The `\n` in the format string matches *any number of whitespace characters*, so the function won't return until you enter a non-whitespace character.  You can fix this by removing `\n` from the format string.

```
scanf("%s",string[i]);
```

Comment: I tried removing the \n in both cases I got the following outputs:

Case 1-
Enter no of strings: 3

Enter string 0: abc
def

Enter string 1: ghi

Enter string 2: jkl

Printing Stored Strings
Enter string 0: abc
Enter string 1: def
Enter string 2: ghi

Case 2-
Enter no of strings: 3

Enter string 0: abc
def

Enter string 1: ghi

Enter string 2: jkl

Printing Stored Strings
Enter string 0: abc
Enter string 1: def
Enter string 2: ghi

Comment: @sdnemina Aside from the poor formatting in the comments, that looks right.  How does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: Notice that i had to enter def before "Enter string 1" and also had to enter 'jkl' in the output it shows Printing Stored Strings Enter string 0: abc Enter string 1: def Enter string 2: ghi  . Also apologies about the formatting as well as using 'Enter String' while printing the outputs too.

Comment: @dbug Error from my side , the suggested change fixed the issue. Thanks